# Wrapping JsUnit in JUnit

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsunit

I'm required to use JSUnit in my Spring-MVC project. It seems that I could write some test pages, include some of my js files, write some tests, and load up my pages with the testRunner. Fine.

But the jsunit download comes with a jsunit.jar, which implies to me that I should be able to control this process from a JUnit test. Maybe even without a test page? I don't know, because I can't find any examples of how to use jsunit.jar.

I'd much rather see some examples than instantiate every class contained in the jar file and see what methods it has available, and surely you all can sympathize. Can someone either point me to some examples or paste in a simple one here to get me started?

Many thanks.

**Edit**

My goal is to wrap JsUnit in JUnit, so that I can right click on the project and run as JUnit, and have my JsUnit test suite executed (so I have renamed my question to reflect my intentions). If jsunit.jar is not the way to go, then perhaps someone knows another way, i.e. loading up test pages with Selenium, or something else. I have seen some solutions that run the test suite when I build the project, and while this may indeed be handy, it is not the solution I seek. I want my test suite to be run locally in an automated fashion, not just when I deploy, and I want them to be launched from my JUnit test suite so that I don't require two different processes to run all my tests.

**Edit**

From jsunit.net:

The JsUnit server addresses 3 needs:

1. Logging of results as XML (in the same format that JUnit uses)
2. **Running JsUnit tests from JUnit** or Ant on one or more browsers
3. Running JsUnit tests from JUnit or Ant on one or more remote machines, each of which has different OSs and browsers

Clearly JsUnit tests can be run from JUnit. Surely somebody has done this before. Examples please!!

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, the jsUnit team has implemented this:

- http://jsunit.berlios.de/reports/jsunit/index.html
- http://developer.berlios.de/projects/jsunit/

The test for their JsUnitRhinoRunner should get you started:

http://jsunit.berlios.de/reports/jsunit/xref-test/de/berlios/jsunit/JsUnitRhinoRunnerTest.html

This is part of the jsUnit Java source.

Comment: Reading my question more carefully would reveal that I am aware of the existence of an implementation, but that I am unable to find any examples showing how to use it.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like this fits the bill. :)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to wrap your JsUnit tests into JUnit.
What about using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to run those tests? There is a fine plugin for that: [Maven-testlol-plugin](https://github.com/bodil/testlol). It runs test js files without starting a browser, using [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) javascript engine and [envjs](http://www.envjs.com/) for simulating a browser environment.

Comment: This looks like it will run JsUnit tests when I run a build, which does look handy, but my goal is really to wrap my JsUnit tests into JUnit, as you suggested. I'd like to run my project as a JUnit test and have all my JsUnit test suite executed. It seems like I should be able to accomplish this with jsunit.jar or selenium, but the documentation is practically non-existent so I'm hoping that someone with experience in this area can give me some pointers.